# Do we perfom queries to the event store? When and how?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am new to event sourcing, but as fas as I have understood when we have a command use case, we instantiate an aggregate in memory, apply events to it from the event store so as to be in the correct state, make the proper changes and then store those changes back to the event store. We also have a read model store that will eventually be updated by these changes.

In my case I have a `CreateUserUseCase` (which is a command use case) and I want to first check if the user already exists and if the username is already taken. For example something like this:

```
        const userAlreadyExists = await this.userRepo.exists(email);

        if (userAlreadyExists) {
           return new EmailAlreadyExistsError(email);
        }

        const alreadyCreatedUserByUserName = await this.userRepo
        .getUserByUserName(username);

        if (alreadyCreatedUserByUserName) {
           return new UsernameTakenError(username);
        }

        const user = new User(username, password, email);
        await this.userRepo.save(user);
```

So, for the `save` method I would use the event store and append the uncommitted events to it. What about the `exists` and `getUserByUserName` methods though? On the one hand I want to make a specific query so I could use my read model store to get the data that I need, but on the other hand this makes a contradiction with CQRS. So what do we do in these cases? Do we, in some way, perform queries to the event store? And in what way do we do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQRS shouldn't be interpreted as "don't query the write model" (because the process of determining state from the write model for the purpose of command processing entails a query, this restriction is untenable).  Instead, interpret it as "it's perfectly acceptable to have a different data model for a query than the one you use for handling intentions to update".  This formulation implies that if the write model is a good fit for a given query, it's OK to execute the query against the write model.

Event sourcing in turn is arguably (especially in conjunction with certain usage styles) the ultimate in data models that optimize for write vs. read and accordingly the event-sourced model makes nearly all queries outside of a fairly small set so inefficient that some form of CQRS is needed.

What query facilities an event store includes are typically limited, but the one query anything that's a suitable event store will have (because it's needed for replaying the events) is a compound query that amounts to "give me the latest snapshot for that entity and either (if the snapshot exists) the first *n* events after that snapshot or (if no snapshot) the first *n* events for that entity".  The result of that query is dispositive (modulo things like retention etc.) to the question of "has this entity published events"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ok I understand that it's not "don't query the write model" thing, but as you said I had in mind that the queries would be "give me the first n events for that entity by id". How do we get the events by email or username for example? Will we store to the event store events by all the potential keys? (id, email, username)

Comment: That is one way you can do it.  You can store an event for an email-address entity with "this email wants to create a user with this username": it doesn't imply anything about the username's existence, but it does mean that (unless/until contradicted by a subsequent event like "turns out that username exists, so this email isn't attempting to create a user with that name" or maybe "this email was disassociated from that username"; you might also have a "yep, that username was created, so consider this email an alias for that username" event).

Comment: Your event store might also support tagging events, conceivably with support for a high enough cardinality of tags that you can tag events for user accounts with the email address and query by tag.

Comment: Hello Levi! I also wanted to ask about the case that we proceed with the approach of saving to the event store events by all the potential keys (id, email, username). Then when appending an event to the event store, do we have to update all the write models (with keys: id, email, username) transactionally?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be transactional.  If the email and username are part of the event, then you could have something that projects the events keyed by id into events keyed by email/username.